# Padding of ListView in SwipeRefreshLayout

Tags: java, android, listview, swiperefreshlayout

I use a ListView inside SwipeRefreshLayout. And Refresh works properly only if ListView paddings are left and right. As soon as I set topPadding or bottomPadding, the Refresh disappears.

**XML:**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_below="@+id/toolBar"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:srl_direction="both">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="@dimen/five_dp"
    android:listSelector="@color/transparent_color"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/five_dp"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/five_dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Now the first item in the list sticks to the ToolBar, so the need padding. With CardView I tried it, but also not approached.

How to fix it, tell me?

Comment: Try to put margin top to swipe refresh layout.

Comment: the top will be empty transparent space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This helped me.

```
if (position == 0){
        convertView.setPadding(0,8,0,0);
} else if (position == getCount() - 1){
        convertView.setPadding(0,0,0,8);
} else {
        convertView.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
}
```

Comment: Where do you put this code? Is there a solution in xml?